# How to display all the list values to Einstein Bot without mentioning the Index like myListvar[0].name?

Tags: customer-community, einstein-chatbot

Please help on this. I am returning a list of variable with multiple records. But I want the list of records to be shown without pointing to each index because list size can be sometimes lesses or more. Because Under the Message Action of Einstein Bot I have to give the index then only it is showing the value . For example : myListVar[0].Name
myListVar[0].Phone.
myListVar[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0APW.png).Name and so on..
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
for (variable : list_or_set) {
    code_block
}
```

When executing this type of for loop, the Apex runtime engine assigns variable to each element in list_or_set, and runs the code_block for each value.

Example:

```
for(String name: myListvar){
    System.debug(name);
}
```

Comment: Where I can write this for loop inside Einstein bot? I don't see any loop action where I can write this. Please suggest,

Comment: I thought you were invoking an apex class from your bot using a Apex invocation action.  As long as the Apex method has a particular annotation (@InvocableMethod) you can invoke small snippets and get them processed in smaller modular functions.

Comment: You are correct I am returning the list of records and my method is invocable. From Bot I called this method and I got the list of records, I stored it in bot variable but now I am stuck to display it dynamically as there are no Loop Actions or anything to show dynamically.

Comment: Please check this is how m doing. what should i do now?

Comment: @Rene have you found the solution for this? I also need to show all the values in my chatbot.